# Reference multiple image table ids in single 'post' table row?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I built a social app with React/Express/Relay and PostgreSQL and currently I have a `post` table which has an image_id field storing a string reference to a pk in the `image` table.

So far so good, but this only works for a single image in a post.

What is the best practice or pattern for storing multiple image id strings in a single post table row, **and** have them each reference a pk in the image table?

*I'm somewhat of a noobie to full stack development so forgive my broad and agnostic question.*

Answer (score 1):

You can store the reference to `post` id for each created image. In this way, you can create multiple images and link each of them to the same post.

To retrieve all the **images** for a single **post**, you will use a query something like this:
`SELECT * FROM IMAGE WHERE post_id=?` where `?` placeholder will be replaced with related post id.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @asgarov Thanks I'll try this today and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

You should store `JSON` string format to insert uncountable image id on SQL. See this link to help you:
https://www.sitepoint.com/use-json-data-fields-mysql-databases/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use a relation of `1 to N`. That is, a post has multiple images. The design of its tables is as follows.

> The post table gives its main key as an Foreign key to the image
> table.

```
table post : ID,Title,....
```

---

```
table image: ID,Post_ID,Url => Post_ID Foreign Key to Post Table
```

---

**Example**

post table:

```
(1,'post 1'),
(2,'post 2'),
(3,'post 3');
```

---

image table:

```
(1,1,'url_post11'),
(2,1,'url_post12'),
(3,2,'url_post21'),
(4,3,'url_post31'),
(5,3,'url_post32');
```